# Deductions from monotonic functions

Tags: functions

We consider the functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} :f\left( x\right) + 2f\left( 1-x\right) =g\left( x\right) $.If g is decreasing, what can we say about f?

I've took $x=0$ and $x=1$ and I had obtained $f(0)< f(1)$ and I find $
f\left( x\right) =\dfrac {-g\left( x\right) +2g\left( 1-x\right) }{3}$

Answer (score 3):

If $g$ is decreasing, $-g$ is increasing. Moreover, $1-x$ is decreasing. Can you conclude something about $g(1-x)$ and in turn about $f$?

Comment: Is increasing 